# Check size of multiple uploaded files

Tags: django

I have a feature that allows users to upload multiple files. I want to check the size of these files and dissallow files that are too large

```
images = request.FILES['images'].size

if images > settings.MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE:
    raise Exception(f'Image {images} is too large 3mb max')
```

I have been playing with this code but I cannot figure out a way to loop over all of the files.

What confuses me about this is i am not iterating over all the files but it still properly throws the exception no matter what order the file that is too large appears in.

Is this code working properly?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use [**`.getlist(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist) to obtain the list of files:

```
for image in request.FILES.getlist('images'):
    if image.size > settings.MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE:
        raise Exception(f'Image {images} is too large 3mb max')
```